# sessionStorage returning undefined value error

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, session-storage

I'm using [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

But I am getting  *undefined* value error then after refresh i get the value.

```
$scope.welcomeMsg = "Welcome!" + " " + sessionStorage.name;
```

[image]

Please help why I am getting this error.

Comment: How do you store the value?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of angular-local-storage provides

```
localStorageService.get(key)
```

as the method to retrieve values from whatever storageprovider you've configured angular-local-storage to use.

If you want to use the native `sessionStorage`, I believe you must use

```
sessionStorage.getItem(key)
```

to retrieve the value [according to the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: It gives null now

Comment: That's because you're not setting the value then. Could you include the code where you store/set the value in your storage?